# Copy audio and image to clipboard onClick div

Tags: javascript, html, audio, copy

I'm trying to copy the audio and, in this case, an emoji, to the clipboard when a div is clicked or tapped. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="box" onclick="stopPlayHTMLBeep();" id="item01"></div>
<audio id="beep" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/263133__pan14__tone-beep.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

JS:

```
 function stopPlayHTMLBeep () {
    document.getElementById("beep").load();
    document.getElementById("beep").play();
 }
```

Comment: This will NOT be possible since it would be a major security risk. Dont follow this path. Offer your user a download option when they click the div.

Comment: Ok, but for ease of use, it would be ideal for the user to quickly tap a div, and then copy it elsewhere. Is this possible to do with both audio and an emoji?

Comment: Emjoi since it is text, yes. This should be possible. but for audio i dont see it going anywhere. As I said this would be a major security risk. Imagine a website could paste whatever file they want into your clipboard.

Comment: @Aaron What about something like 'long tap' on mobile safari that calls up the 'copy' action sheet? How might I make the divs contents 'copyable'?

Comment: I dont use iOS but I'm guessing it is still a simple file download in the background. You can also leftclick images etc and download them but this isnt what you asked for.

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, so let's say I have a div with an audio file and an emoji (text), how might I specify that what is inside the div is 'copyable' after long tap?

Comment: if you save either to the server or locally to the client what the client clicked on to indicate intention to save something then later when the client indicates a paste action your system would paste using that prior knowledge